# JLabel no se ve en jProgressBar

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un `JProgressBar` y un `JLabel` lo que pretendo es mostrar el % de avance por encima del `JProgessBar` pero cuando agrego el `JLabel` sobre el `JProgressBar` este no se ve, solo se visualiza el `JProgressBar`.

Hay alguna forma de sobreponer un control por encima del otro?

Asi lo tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clase `JProgressBar` puede mostrar textualmente su valor de progreso, solo que por defecto su propiedad *booleana* `stringPainted` está inicializada en `false`.

Simplemente se debe especificar lo contrario así:

`miBarra.setStringPainted(true);`

Comment: Se puede cambiar el color del StringPainted?
Ya que el color de este es el mismo que el del ProgresBar y no se visualiza del todo bien al ir cargando la barra.

Comment: Si, como a todo `JComponent` a través del método `setForeground()`

Comment: Gracias, Solucionado!!!!